# How to add custom pre-requisites while creating msi installer of my windows application using setup and deployment project

Tags: vb.net, winforms, setup-project

I have a windows application for which i want to create a msi installer of the project.
I have some prerequisites component required for running the application. 
How to add these component.

Answer (score 0):

The standard answer is to use the Bootstrap Manifest Generator, but it's hard to find and not well documented. The install, BMG2008Setup.msi is still out there (I downloaded it yesterday). That's the only choice to customize for VS setups as far as I know. The source code may be out there somewhere too.

In general you need to know how to detect that the prerequisite is already installed and the command line to install it. Detection might be registry or MSI ProductCode based and take account of 64-bit/32-bit. Exactly what is the prerequisite?